# Implementing Custom Membership user and Custom Membership Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, overriding, membership-provider, membershipuser

#### References

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730.aspx

#### Question

In the 2nd link precisely under heading `Create a Custom Membership Provider` you will note that they mention this

> You will need to create a custom membership provider that supports
>   both your custom membership user type, and your custom membership data
>   store. The GetUser and CreateUser methods of the custom membership
>   provider can be written to return objects of the custom membership
>   user type.

below is my custom membership user with custom fields

#### Custom Membership User

```
 public class CustomMembershipUser : MembershipUser
    {
        //private fields for internal use
        private bool _isMarried;
        private bool _hasLicense;
        private string _address;
        private int _userId;

        //public fields for use by end user

        public int UserId
        {
            get { return _userId; }
            set { _userId = value; }
        }
...
```

#### Custom Membership Provider

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
    {
        .....

        public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
....
```

I did exactly what they told me to do, return membership user of my custom type like this

```
public override **CustomMembershipUser** CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
```

but then i was complained by the IDE that 
**Cannot Change return type when overriding MembershipProvider.CreateUser**. So what am i supposed to do now,

- Create another method with same parameters and return custom membership user?
- I don't have any need for password question, security question fields how do i get rid of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return a `MembershipUser` instance in the function which is the return type for it. Currently it isn't returning what it is supposed to return.

There is a good tutorial at codeproject : [Custom Membership Providers](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CustomMembershipProviders.aspx). You might find it helpful in understanding where you aren't getting right.

Comment: you failed to answer the question 2 from the bullets at the end of post

Comment: You will have to implement them. It comes as a package :-) . The MembershipProvider abstract class inherits the ProviderBase abstract class from the System.Configuration.Provider namespace, so you must implement the required members of the ProviderBase class as well. Visit [Required MembershipProvider Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) for knowing what needs to be implemented in order to get it working

Comment: just another thought, what if i inherited providerbase and implement my own version of MembershipProvider will it work with the membership components.

Comment: hmm...in that case you can get rid of them. But then again why reinvent the wheel. You will need to do a lot(a lot) more work to implement ProviderBase directly for just a little requirement

Comment: one more question, if membership user provides all info about user what is the use of a `Profile Provider` explain as you would for a layman.

Comment: You are getting bit confused. This is what these particular providers offer you with : (1) **Membership** - Authentication for a user (username/password) (2) **Role** - Authorization for a user (IsAdmin? IsPowerUser?) (3) **Profile**- Details about a user (phone number, age, date of birth)

Answer (score -1):

You should not create a new method that return CustomMembershipUser.

You should have only **MembershipUser CreateUser(...)** in the custom membership provider. Before your return you need to cast the CustomMembershipUser to be MembershipUser.

E.g. out following when you return.

return (MembershipUser)new CustomMembershipUser();

Comment: well the compiler handled the casting for me, i just need to return my `custommembershipuser`, in the application i will have to recast it that's all.

Comment: You don't need to cast to the base class, it will be done implicitly.