# Using User.Identity how do I get the User's First Name from the profile?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Using Websecurity or Membership how do I get the stored user first name of the current user?
I can easily get the username but I would like to use the saved First Name in a greeting.

Comment: How do you store a user's first name in your database?

Comment: You'll most likely want to create a Custom MembershipProvider if you haven't already.  This SO question should help you if you need direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090350/implementing-custom-membership-user-and-custom-membership-provider

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360126/simplemembership-with-custom-database-schema-in-asp-net-mvc-4?rq=1 should give you a place to start.