# How to extend MembershipUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to write a custom login routine and I'm using the `MembershipUser` class `GetUser` function which is working perfectly.

However I'd like to get the user based on a different column other than username. How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

probably following link will help you :
[implementing-custom-membership-user-and-custom-membership-provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090350/implementing-custom-membership-user-and-custom-membership-provider)
otherwise your solution will be asp.net identity